# NaNs in pandas.DataFrame not printing to Excel

Tags: python, excel, numpy, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` which contains `numpy.nan` floats. When using the Excel writer however, the fields where there should be `numpy.nan` floats are blank. I would expected at least a string representation instead of nothing.

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Writer code is as follows:

```
writer=pandas.ExcelWriter('output.xls')
frame.to_excel(writer,'tab name')
writer.save()
```

Where `frame` looks something like this (note the NaN on 2013-01-1):

```
        Series ID Risk Bucket   Contract  PX Last  Contract Value (Local)  Currency X  Contract Value (USD)    Currency
2013-01-01  Future_ES          EQ  ES1 Index      NaN                     NaN           1                   NaN  USD Curncy
2013-01-02  Future_ES          EQ  ES1 Index  1447.16                 72362.5           1               72362.5  USD Curncy
2013-01-03  Future_ES          EQ  ES1 Index  1443.68                 72187.5           1               72187.5  USD Curncy
2013-01-04  Future_ES          EQ  ES1 Index  1447.90                 72400.0           1               72400.0  USD Curncy
```

But the Excel file has blanks (see attached image).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), you should set the option `na_rep` in `to_excel` with a string of your liking. E.g.:

```
frame.to_excel(writer,'tab name', na_rep='NA')
```

Comment: Strange, I'm using 0.9.1 which does not have that feature documented nor could I exactly pin point it in the source (Github) however it works, thanks.

Comment: @strimp099 it's in the codebase [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L1412) and in the 0.9.1 docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.9.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) (though recommend updating to latest stable).